# Given a list of nested tibbles how do I map function to each object?

Tags: r, nested, purrr

I have a list of nested tibbles (which includes lists themselves etc, sort of like inception).

```
library(tidyverse)

# example function I want to apply
fun1 <- function(data) {
  minimum <- min(data$Sepal.Length)

  return(minimum)
}


# example of nested list
list_nested_tibbles <- list(
  list1 = iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest(),
  list2 = iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest()
)


# applying function to one of the nested tibbles within the list
list_nested_tibbles$list1 %>% mutate(minimum = map_dbl(.x = data, ~ fun1(.x)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    data              minimum
#>   <fct>      <list>              <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>     4.3
#> 2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>     4.9
#> 3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>     4.9

# function fails if I apply across whole list
list_nested_tibbles %>% mutate(minimum = map_dbl(.x = data, ~ fun1(.x)))
#> Error in UseMethod("mutate"): no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "list"
```

However, I want to apply the function to both list items simultaneously, I'm guessing I need some sort of nested map statement?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What about the `lapply()` function? Or maybe you could use the `Map()` function as well, defining your desired function as the fisrt argument.

Comment: So, in the example I provided if you use 
map(list_nested_tibbles, function(x) { x %>% mutate(minimum = map_dbl(.x = data, ~ fun1(.x)))}) it works. However, in my actual dataset each object within the list is a [1] "vctrs_list_of" "vctrs_vctr"    "list"  and when I have the same function it causes an error saying Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('vctrs_list_of', 'vctrs_vctr', 'list')"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know how to re-create exact structure. I used group_split() from tidyverse to create the object.

Comment: In the end I had to do this: ```map(list_nested_tibbles , function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(x) {
    x %>% mutate(minimum= map(.x = data, ~ fun1(.x)))
  })
})```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `purrr` functions:

```r
map(list_nested_tibbles, ~ .x %>% mutate(minimum = map_dbl(data, ~ fun1(.x))))
```

```
$list1
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    data              minimum
  <fct>      <list>              <dbl>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>     4.3
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>     4.9
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>     4.9

$list2
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    data              minimum
  <fct>      <list>              <dbl>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>     4.3
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>     4.9
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>     4.9
```